# What tool captures full web page screenshots including CSS transforms?

Tags: website-design, screenshot

I have been using Ember and Paparazzi in the past. The design I am working on has several images with perspective and CSS Transforms. As a result the image frames are distorted like an object in three-dimensional space.

I have tried several alternatives like Snagit and Pixave, but none captures the transform effects.

Comment: At least my SnagIt does seem to do what you claim it does not... Perhaps you need a better explanation with pictures.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't deal with graphic design. You might be able to get help on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I already solved my own problem by using Photoshop to make a composite of normal screenshots. For some reason SnagIt did not do the job on my prototype, neither did other tools.

PS If you think this is not about graphic design, then I want to have a forum for using pencil and paper. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LightShort](http://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html) to capture a specific area and edit it at the same time.

I have used it. It's pretty good and very useful for me. I hope it will help you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I did try the App version, but AFAIK it does not take full-page screenshots (outside what you see in the viewport). Or maybe the extension does?